# Is there a way to "copy" the MessageBox functionality in Windows Mobile 6.5?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

is there a way to "copy" the functionality of a MessageBox or DialogBox in Windows Mobile 6.5?

I've developed a custom message box (with paint events and blending etc) to make the UI look better. However, I don't know how to duplicate the MessageBox functionality, where the program "freezes" and "waits" for a response from the user (usually pressing OK or Cancel button).

Right now, as a workaround, I disable the entire screen so that only the message box will receive any key presses. Then have a custom event called OnMessageBoxClosed.

I then put the actual code to be executed based on the choice made by the user (OK or Cancel) in the event handler for the event.

I would prefer if its possible to make this custom message box behave like a regular messagebox.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean how to make it a modal dialog?

Comment: yes a modal dialog that can stop "code execution" while waiting for a response from the user

Comment: Just use ShowDialog() instead of Show().